# Keel.sh not seeing pods

Tags: kubernetes, cicd, gitops

For those who gave a try to [keel.sh](https://keel.sh) .. how to make it detects image referenced in pods ?
For the moment, it only detect docker images mentioned within deployments. What if I need to track the image of a single pod?

This is weird cause in the installation manifests, under the ClusterRole, it asks for `get`, `watch`, `list` verbs on pods the same as for deployments:

```
resources:
  - pods
  - replicasets
  - replicationcontrollers
  - statefulsets
  - deployments
  - daemonsets
  - jobs
  - cronjobs
verbs:
  - get
  - delete # required to delete pods during force upgrade of the same tag
  - watch
  - list
  - update
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, stop looking... until the date of this answer Keel watch only for images in `Deployment`, `statefulsets`, `daemonsets`, `cronjobs` as we can see in its [source code](https://github.com/keel-hq/keel/blob/master/internal/k8s/watcher.go)

So if you want to automatically update images within your custom resources or something else than the list above don't waste your time !

Please don't hesitate to post an answer here if this have been changed..